# Cannot find symbol method initCause

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

This is the output I'm getting while compiling my class under Lubuntu 12.04 32bit + jdk1.6.0_33 + Intellij IDEA 11.1.2:

> Cannot find symbol method initCause(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Language level of the project is '5 enum word'.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Can you please explain to me what's the problem here and how to fix it?

P.S. it's a SUN jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must apologize - the problem is not specific to linux.

It is because of the difference between JavaSE and JavaME:

Both, SE and ME have class **java.lang.Throwable**.

ME implementation does not have initCause() method - that was the actual reason why the code didn't compile.

It seems that I have copy/pasted this code from SE project to ME without checking.

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough details in your question but from what i understand you have a Class with a method initCause() that accepts an object, and that object is not in your class path so what you need to do, is find the jar/project that contains this class and add it to your classpath.

It would be helpful if you post a code sample (the one that fails) and how are you executing it (with the IDE or in the command line).

Comment: I do not visibly call such a method (initCause). 
The code is supplied on the screenshot - it's a double check locking singleton. 
The problem appears in the line 11: 'synchronized (Singleton.class) {'

Comment: I also use SUN WTK 2.5.2. Is this article below has something to do with my question? http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/db-derby-dev/200707.mbox/%3C46AF3EBA.5020703@Sun.COM%3E

Comment: What is this: "Language level of the project is '5 enum word'. "?

Comment: Try compiling it in a lesser version (1.4) and see if it helps.

Comment: Unknowing what the problem is I'd suggest using a dedicated object for locking, instead of a class

Comment: @ftom2   Compiling it in any version (1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6) didn't help... Is there anything else I can try to do?